# Hide image on mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress, image, hide

I'm trying to hide a specific image that messes up the layout of my website for mobile devices. I'm using a wordpress website and I want to utilize the "custom CSS plugin" for this function.

I have already pieced some information together, and apparently I have to use the following to target devices that have a width-resolution of 400 pixels;

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px)

Now I need to target that specific image, but this is where I need some pointers. I know that to disable the image I can use display: none;, but that still leaves me with targetting the image in question.

Any tips would be welcome, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, with CSS, you can try this:

let's say your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="foo">
   <img src="bar.png" align="right">
   <img src="cat.png" align="right"> 
</div>
```

These attribute selectors select by the "begins with".

```
img[src^=bar] { css }
img[src^=cat] { css }
```

These select by "contains".

```
img[src*="bar"] { css }
img[src*="cat"] { css }
```

Or you can select by the exact src.

```
img[src="bar.png"] { css }
img[src="cat.png"] { css }
```

If you want to target them both, then you could use the div id.

```
#foo img { css }
```

If you want to select the first-child of the div containing the images

```
#foo img:first-child {
    /* css */
}
```

If you want to target a specific child of the containing div

```
#foo img:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* css */
}
```

Hope this helps!